# What are the implementation of default accessors in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a class like this

```
class Square(var width: Int, var height: Int) {
    var color : String = "red"
}
```

As my understanding Kotlin's compiler will consider width, height and color are properties of class Square and therefore it will generate setter and getter for these properties automatically.

With property color, i guess the getter and setter of it should be liked this

```
var color : String = "red"
get() = field
set(value) { field = value}
```

But how about the default setter and getter of the width and height properties. These properties don't have initialization values so they can't have "field"  identifier in the getter and setter. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: I don't see the connection between using the `field` identifier and initial value being present.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik in Kotlin if you don't use "field" identifier inside the body of getter or setter then the property may not need to be initialized, for example:

class Square(var width: Int, var height: Int) {

    val isSquare : Boolean
        get() = width == height        
}

but if you change the getter of "isSquare" like this 
get() = field then the property "isSquare" must be initialized.

Comment: Because in the first example there's no backing field at all, it's a computed property. This still has no connection to having a default value. In your case all properties will have a backing field, it's only that one has a default value and the other two must be passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties placed in the header of a class declaration are a convenience if you need to store simple properties in a class, and you want to initialize them through constructor arguments with the same names. If you use these, you give up the ability to give them custom setters and getters - this can only be done for properties in the body of the class.

Otherwise, the default implementation of their getters (and setters for `var`s) are the same as for properties in the class body. They just return (and set) the value of the backing field.

Edit, following up on the comments above: this also means that the properties in the constructor always have to be initialized, they can't be computed properties, since you can't give them getters and setters that wouldn't use their backing field.